# C++ arrays with user input size (aka Why does this compile?)

Tags: arrays, memory-leaks, clang, dynamic-memory-allocation

I was experimenting with clang (10.0) on win 10, with the following snippet:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  const int N = 10;

  int ii;
  cout << "Enter value for ii: ";
  cin >> ii;

  int a[N+ii];

  for (int i = 0; i < N+ii; ++i) {
    a[i] = 0;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < N+ii; ++i) {
    cout << "a[ " << i << "] = " << a[i] << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I am not sure as to **Why are there no compilation error** (the size of the array `a` is unkown at compile time) ????

PS:

1. Both `for` loops were meant to trigger segmentation fault.
2. command to compile: `clang.exe exp.cpp`
3. I have tried to run the code with large values for `ii` but it seems to work fine (ii = 10000, 100000, 1000000)

Comment: Because some compilers support VLAs from `c` related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> int a[N+ii];

This is ill-formed in C++. The size of an array variable must be compile time constant.

> I am not sure as to Why are there no compilation error (the size of the array a is unkown at compile time) ????

The C++ standard does **not** require that ill-formed programs could not be compiled. When a compiler intentionally compiles an ill-formed program, you are using a language extension.

The standard does require that the language implementation issues a diagnostic message, informing the user of their ill-formed program. Clang doesn't conform to the standard unless you provide the `-pedantic` option when compiling. If you do use it, this is what clang says:

> ```
> warning: variable length arrays are a C99 feature [-Wvla-extension]
> ```

And this is what clang document says about the option:

> ```
> -pedantic, --pedantic, -no-pedantic, --no-pedantic
> ```
>
> Warn on language extensions